# Oracle SQL: How to combine results when one value has two possible answers

Tags: sql, oracle

This is an Oracle SQL conundrum.

I have a problem where I've a table of dates/fruit/quantity consumed where there are occasional duplicates in the Fruit table that I want to clean up.  For instance, where I'd have 3 Apples and 2 Apples eaten on the same day, and I want to combine it to JUST say 5 apples eaten.

I would guess it uses the GROUP BY function, but I can't figure out a way to avoid grouping ALL apples rather than just all apples on a specific date.

```
    Date    Fruit   Eaten
    1-May   Lemon   2
    1-May   Apple   3
    1-May   Apple   2
    1-May   Orange  4
    2-May   Lemon   1
    2-May   Apple   2
    2-May   Orange  3
    2-May   Pear    4
```

Here is what I would LIKE it to look like:

```
   Date     Fruit   Eaten
   1-May    Lemon   2
   1-May    Apple   5
   1-May    Orange  4
   2-May    Lemon   1
   2-May    Apple   2
   2-May    Orange  3
   2-May    Pear    4
```

Comment: Have you tried to group by on two columns ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select to_char(Date, 'DD-MON') as Date,Fruit,sum(Eaten) as Eaten
from Your_Table
group by to_char(Date, 'DD-MON') ,Fruit
```

or try to use `trunc` as below:

```
select trunc(Date, 'MONTH') as Date,Fruit,sum(Eaten) as Eaten
from Your_Table
group by trunc(Date, 'MONTH') ,Fruit
```

Comment: That actually ended up returning 5 Apples eaten on May 1st twice rather than just once.

Comment: @user2006985 - It either returned the same result as your input due to having different times or it returned one record with the correct sum but what you are saying just doesn't make sense. Can you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

Try to group on more than one column :

```
select Date,Fruit,sum(Eaten)
from Your_Table
group by Date,Fruit
```

Comment: Might be a good idea to use `trunc` on the data to remove the time part.